# can i find out when a webpage was last uploaded?

Tags: datetime, web, upload, ftp

as the question asks, is there a way of finding when a page was uploaded/updated last. I've got a client who has an 'SEO' company and I've just been asked by client if i've changed the the ftp login details, i haven't but it could be the seo company, want to know if they've updated a page and uploaded it after i did....

thanks in advance....

Comment: well, have you looked at the filetime of the page? eg. login via ftp and look at the date the page was modified?

Comment: Wait, do you have access to the ftp server login or not? It sounds to me like you *don't*, but other people seem to read it as you *do*...

Comment: @Gabe: He said "uploaded it after I did". I assumed that meant he had upload access.

Comment: what i needed was 

javascript:alert(document.lastModified)

Comment: Then in the end I was right. document.lastModified works by checking the page headers for a Last-Modified date. If that header weren't set, document.lastModified wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server provides a "last-modified" header, that would give you the most reliable information without accessing their servers.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, log into the FTP and take a look at the creation date of the file.

Comment: meaning: your ftp client should show you that value for each file/directory

Answer (score 0):

```
javascript:alert(document.lastModified)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
javascript:alert(document.lastModified)
```

wiil do it